# could not find an object to spy upon for navigateBackToLanding

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

While running my test, I'm getting this error `could not find an object to spy upon for navigateBackToLanding`.

I've searched and done all the steps which was mention, but still i'm getting the error

```
 could not find an object to spy upon for navigateBackToLanding
```

Not sure what I'm missing out here.

**component.ts**

```
  ngOnInit () {
    this.bwcPageTemplateCommunicatorService.subheader.next({
      title: this.title,
      backAction: {
        label: 'back',
        callback: () => this.navigateBackToLanding()
      }
    });
  }

  public navigateBackToLanding () {
    this.router.navigate(['portal']);
  }
```

**component spec.ts**

```
describe('CpDetailPageComponent', () => {
  let component: CpDetailPageComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CpDetailPageComponent>;
  let onClickMock;
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
      imports: [RouterTestingModule],
      declarations: [CpDetailPageComponent],
      providers: [
        BwcPageTemplateCommunicatorService,
        BwcTocService,
        BwcScrollSpyService,
        BwcScrollService
      ]
    });
    TestBed.compileComponents();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CpDetailPageComponent);
    onClickMock = spyOn(component, 'navigateBackToLanding').and.callThrough();
  }));

  it('should call navigateBackToLanding method', () => {
    fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button')).triggerEventHandler('click', null);
    expect(onClickMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<button class="bwc-subheader__button-back ng-star-inserted" mat-icon-button="" type="button" aria-label="back"></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's quite simple: you never initialize the variable `component` anywhere. So there's no object to spy upon, as the error message says, since `component` is undefined.

```
component = fixture.componentInstance;
onClickMock = spyOn(component, 'navigateBackToLanding').and.callThrough();
```

Comment: Thanks, now I'm getting this error `Failed: Cannot read property 'click' of null
`

Comment: That probably means that there is no button in the DOM, probably because you haven't called fixture.detectChanges().

Comment: `button` markup is created using the service, it won't be available by default in html file. I've add the generated html  code in my question

Comment: Also I tried `query(By.css('.bwc-subheader__button-back'))` still no luck

Comment: You can't dynamically generate code that way with Angular (unless you ship the compiler and compile templates on the fly, which is exactly what the AOT compilation is meant to avoid). Change your design. HTML is supposed to be generated by component templates, not by services. Anyway, I can't do remote debugging without seeing any code. I answered your original question, now take some time to research the next problems.